# FuseFabric - Add a config file via console

Tags: fuseesb, jbossfuse, karaf, fusefabric, gogo-shell

In FuseFabric we can add configuration files using the web console, using the Config Files Tab and just write the name of the configFile and inside it the properties foo=foo

Well, this is very simple, and my question is: How can I do this using the Fabric console ??

just typing commands ????? D:

I've seen the fabric:profile and its options, and I can edit the properties, but only when there is an already existing PID.

Thank you for every answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
fabric:profile-edit --pid PID/Property=Value Profile [Version]
```

Otherwise, maintaining property files on the file system and using `import` to re-import the settings works fine also.

Use `profile-display` to see the correct PID.

Comment: YES ! Thank you vikingSteve.